# Append Value to $_POST Array with jQuery FormData.append

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple HTML Form and in this form there is a section where the user can select one or more checkboxes. 
I have written a JS function that gets the value of every checked box and puts it into a string:

```
function getSupportedDevices() {
    var supportedDevices = "";
    $('.devices:checkbox:checked').each(function () {
        let sThisVal = $(this).val();
        supportedDevices += sThisVal + ";";
    });
    console.log(supportedDevices);

    return supportedDevices;
}
```

This function is called before the Ajax call and the result should be [appended to the FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) so that I can use the string later on. 
Here is the code from where I try to add the list:

```
var $debForm = $('#formDeb');
if ($debForm.length > 0) {
    $debForm.on('submit', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!isSubmitting) {
            let $form = $(this);
            let targetUrl = $form.attr('action');
            let method = $form.attr('method');
            let $btnSubmit = getElement($form, '.js-btn-submit');

            var myFormData = new FormData(this);
            var supportedDevices = getSupportedDevices();
            myFormData.append("supportedDevices", supportedDevices);

            $.ajax({
                type: method,
                url: targetUrl,
                data: myFormData,
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function () { ...
```

Running this code throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
>      at add (jquery.js:8430)
>      at buildParams (jquery.js:8417)
>      at Function.jQuery.param (jquery.js:8450)
>      at Function.ajax (jquery.js:9040)
>      at HTMLFormElement. (submitdeb.js:45)
>      at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5206)
>      at HTMLFormElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:5014)

Line 45 is `$.ajax`. If I try `data: new FormData(this).append("supportedDevices", getSupportedDevices())` as ajax parameter I get no error but the `$_POST` Array is empty.

What am I doing wrong that I get this error? The function to generate the string works on it's own and if I only send the `FormData` without anything appended, the `$_POST` Array is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `processData:false` to prevent `$.ajax` trying to serialize the FormData object using `$.param()` which it does by default when an object is passed to `data`.

The browser will handle the serializing internally